# Link_to Post Request Not Working In Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

To verify, just follow this link:

```
<%= link_to "Verify My Account", @fullUrl, :method => :post %>
```

That is a line of code in my mailer.

Variables I have Defined:

```
url = "http://myurl.com"
confirmationToken = user.confirmation_token
fullUrl= [@url,@confirmationToken].join ("")
```

I also installed `jquery-rails` to render this and still be processed as GET request. Thanks for your help!

---

Updated Code:

```
def new_support(user)
@user = user
@url = "http://myexample.com"
@confirmation_token =user.confirmation_token
@full_url= [@url,@confirmation_token].join
```

Comment: When the link in the email is clicked it processes this as a GET request.

Comment: `url` is a **local variable**, whereas `@url` is an **instance variable**. Same for `confirmationToken` / `@confirmationToken` and `fullUrl` / `@fullUrl`. Although they share the same name, the local variables and their instance variable namesakes are totally unrelated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the built in url helper? It's likely to be something like `confirmation_token_url(user.confirmation_token)`, though run `rake routes` to find it.

Comment: BTW, we use `snake_case` in Ruby for variables and methods.

Comment: Trying to make a link in an email use POST doesn't sound right. Why do you want / need that? Wouldn't it be easier to change the action from POST to GET and use a plain old link?

Comment: When i posted the variables i forgot to put in the @ in front of them for the instance.

Comment: Good call Stefan on changing it from POST to GET, i made the necessary changes. Thank you all for your help ! I appreciate you helping me with the NOOB questions.

Comment: All is working now, thank you !